# Use AOA Alongside Android Auto to Transfer Data?

Tags: android-auto, android-open-accessory

Im using OpenAuto on a Raspberry Pi to be able to play music and do navigation.

Works great.

However I've also written a Car PC app where one Raspberry Pi hooks into the CAN Bus, collects data and passes through a network cable using UDP Broadcast to a second raspberry pi which processes data and dumps it in firebase for a telemtry app on the phone.

This relies on a WiFi hotspot on the car. Im looking at the possibility of adding my C program as an external library to Open Auto so that I can use OpenAuto to manage the registration process of the "car".

But what I want to do now, is get more creative. Im thinking why can't I take advantage of the USB Cable and send data directly to the phone and let the phone take care of processing telemetry.

Im aware in Android Auto there are methods to transfer a limited amount of telemetry data. However unless you acquire a dodgy copy of the Android Auto SDK which hasn't been officially released by Google, then it's my understanding you cannot gain access to that telemetry data, or use Vendor Channels to transfer your own data set.

However I have seen Android Open Accessory Protocol, and was wondering whether this could be used alongside Android Auto to transfer an additional set of data?

Im not interested in projecting anything to the OpenAuto screen, I just want to collect and process data. Maybe add a notification or two for low fuel or ambient temperatures etc. But Im not sure if the two protocols would play nicely alongside each other.

Im guessing that Android Auto would take priority, so I would have to look at getting the Sensor Messages from Android Auto. Does anyone have any bright ideas?